# @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) does not remove null fields from Inner POJO

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, response

I have below response structure. I am using `jackson-databind` version 2.5.1.

```
public class MyResponse {
    private String entity;

    private Detail detail;

    // public Getter and setter
}

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Detail {
    private String name;

    private String location; // location field is null for testing

    // public Getter and setter
}
```

**Problem:** Response includes `location` field even if it is *null*.

**Note:** `@JsonInclude` works on outer object i.e. MyResponse, but it does not works in inner POJO class.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm surprised Jackson serializes private fields. Are you sure it's private? maybe there's a getter somewhere that is public

Comment: Yes, there are public getter/setter.

Comment: In that case, have you put the annotation @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) in front of your getter?

Comment: I will try to put it against getter and get back.

Comment: @ZiglioNZ: I have added @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) annotation for getter also, still json response is showing field with value null. is there any other solution?

Comment: are your members public? try to put the annotation on top of the fields themselves.

Comment: @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) worked fine in my case, maybe should check if jackson used properly